# Application won't startup after FTP download

Tags: macos, ftp, .app

When downloading a `application.App` folder from a FTP server, the application cannot start because the `/Contents/MacOS/application` is recognized as a document. To work properly it shoul be recognized as an executable.

How can I upload a .App folder to FTP so that it can be downloaded and started?

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do would be to package it to a DMG file.

http://bfy.tw/3P7o

Then just add the dmg to the ftp server or zip it up.

Comment: I was thinking this but I was hoping there was a solution to the firs problem.